# Indusoft Web Studio Database error?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, scada, wonderware

I seem to be getting a recurring error with indusoft web studio. My values from my meters seem to have stopped recording to the DB and this is the db messages I get on my IWS log output:

> Database: Error: Fail trying to connect to Studio Database Gateway. If
>   you are running the gateway on a remote computer, make sure that the
>   gateway is running on the same port as you configured in your project.
>   [Connection String: 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Integrated Security=SSPI;
>   Initial Catalog=ABPBandonMIS; Data Source=ABP-BAN-SD-01', Table:
>   'Runtime_Values_Water']
>
> Database: Error: Error to add new register[CMD_ADD] [Connection
>   String: 'Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial
>   Catalog=ABPBandonMIS; Data Source=ABP-BAN-SD-01', Table:
>   'Runtime_Values_Water']

Anybody got any ideas on what is going wrong here or what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Did you change anything to the configuration of your database? (database name, permissions) Runtime_Values_Water, is that the table you are using to keep track of your meter values?

Comment: Nope. Nothing. I think it may be more of a port issue as I keep finding 2 instances running, I kill them and it temporarily fixes the issue.

Comment: This site has a few generic troubleshooting options. `http://proscada.ru/indusoftwebstudio7.en/topics/database_troubleshooting.html` The first message is the important one, its saying the DB can't connect, has the service stopped? Something in your network change?

Comment: When you say instance, you mean database engines? Try to see on which port these 2 instances are running and which user created them (process explorer could help here). Are there other clients connecting to this database?

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 instances running probaly, check your code to always open and close a DBCursor or Instance. Check your DB Dashboard to see if your user is connected.

Try to use the returno code for Indusoft DB functions and process the errors codes.

[Error List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoPj4.png)